# Change cell colour based on another cell containing text (day name)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

I am new to Google Sheets and trying to create a custom formula in conditional formatting to make the fill colour of a cell change based on another cell containing a specific text.

I want to change the colour of cells in column D to grey if cells in column C contain the text "Saturday" or "Sunday".

[image: Example screenshot of part of the spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1):

A custom formula in the Conditional Formatting interface can do this for you. It looks like your dates in Column C are formatted as dates, and not just text. So I'll demonstrate a formula that will work in that case. (If your Column C is just text, you can adjust the formula to look for the strings "Saturday" or "Sunday".)

Select Cell D13. Click on the Fill Color button. Select the `Conditional Formatting` option. In the `Apply to range` box, enter the range you want the condition to apply to. From what I can see in your screenshot, that would be D13:D20, and probably more. In the `Format rules` section, pick `Custom formula is`. Then enter this in the custom formula box:

`=Or(Weekday(C13)=1,Weekday(C13)=7)`

Then under `Formatting style`, select the Fill Color button, and select the shade of grey you prefer. Then click `Done`.

#### Explanation of the formula

The formula will inspect cell C13 (and it will adjust as the range continues downward). It will determine the day of the week that C13 represents. If it is Sunday (1) or Saturday (7), the condition will be true, so the conditional formatting will apply.

Answer (score 1):

- **it's either this:**

  ```
  =COUNTIF($C11, "S*")
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- **or this:**

  ```
  =IF(LEN(C11),IF(OR(TEXT(C11,"ddd")="Sat",TEXT(C11,"ddd")="Sun"),1))
  ```

  [image: 0]

  ---
- **or this:**

  ```
  =IF(LEN(C11),OR(WEEKDAY(C11)=1,WEEKDAY(C11)=7))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

`=OR(D$2="Sat",D$2="Sun")` is the custom formula I use to change column colour if the header (line 2 in the sheet) is Sat or Sun.
To use a full word, just type it inside the quotation marks.
The dollar sign `$` locks the formula to row 2 over the range. So if you put the Dollar Sign `$` in front of the column letter, it will check the column instead of the row.